# Firefox Extension building / SDK, click on a page dom element from within extension

Tags: firefox, sdk

I'm developing a Firefox extension using the latest SDK on FF 31.

In the past (before the SDK was around, years ago), it was possible for the extension to completely manipulate all parts of the page the user was on, for example, change dom elements, etc.

It seems like modifying dom elements is still supported, but I can't seem to be able to fire a "click" even on a DOM element created by the page (not by the extension).

```
// main.js

var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), data.url("my-addon.js")]
});


//my-addon.js

var z = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "here"; });

if(z != null && z.length > 0){

    alert("FOUND IT");
    $(z).click();

}
```

The code above just looks for a link that has "here" as the exact text and tries to click on it. It finds it just fine, but the click action does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

For anyone who has the same problem, add this to the top of your "my-addon.js" script

```
unsafeWindow.click_object = function(_item) {
    _item.click();
}
```

Then you can call it like this (from the same my-addon.js script):

```
unsafeWindow.click_object($(z).get(0));
```